# Can't get Wake On Lan (WOL) to work through internet / DDNS

Tags: networking, router, remote, wake-on-lan, ddns

I'm trying to configure remote WOL for my testing server.

This machine (Windows) is behind my home router; I assigned it a local static IP address.
I successfully woke it from LAN (another laptop connected to home wifi), so WOL is working fine.
My issue is that I can't get it work through the internet. I have configured a DDNS in my home router and enabled UDP ports 7 and 9.

When the test machine is on, I can successfully connect to it using this DDNS name. Also, public IP address is correctly resolved if I try to ping my DDNS name. This make me think it's not a DDSN-related issue.

I tried countless suggestion I found searching the internet, but no luck.

What am I getting wrong?

Any help is truly appreciated!

Comment: What tool are you using to wake up the computer and how?

Comment: To do a remote wake-up you need special assistance from your router:  1/ ability to trigger a script that will do what you did in the LAN or 2/ destination NAT + one of 2a/ static ARP, 2b/ ability to route directed broacast as per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2644#section-3 . If your router is a simple home router which is not "programmable" (eg: running OpenWRT), it's less obvious there will be such features.